# forEach Loop skips the last item

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, eureka-forms

This forEach loop works sometimes and sometimes it skips. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. The loop will skip the last item and will never exit. So the completion block does not get fired at all.

I am using firebase, Eureka forms and it's ImageRow extension.

I would appreciate some help here.

```
//MARK: - Get Form Values
var returnedValues: [String: Any] = [:]
fileprivate func getFormValues(values: [String: Any], completion: @escaping ([String:Any])->()) {

    if let name = values["name"] as? String,
        let description = values["description"] as? String,
        let images = values["images"] as? [UIImage],
        let category = values["category"] as? String,
        let price = values["price"] as? Double,
        let deliveryFee = values["deliveryFee"] as? Double,
        let deliveryAreas = values["deliveryArea"] as? Set<String>,
        let deliveryTime = values["deliveryTime"] as? String {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        var imagesData = [[String: Any]]()
        var counter = 0

        images.forEach({ (image) in

            let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
            let productImageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("product_images").child(uid).child("\(imageName).jpg")
            var resizedImage = UIImage()

            if image.size.width > 800 {
                resizedImage = image.resizeWithWidth(width: 800)!
            }

            if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.5) {
                productImageStorageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Failed to upload image: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                        return
                    }

                    //Successfully uploaded product Image
                    print("Successfully uploaded product Image")
                    if let productImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                        counter += 1
                        let imageData: [String: Any] = [imageName: productImageUrl]
                        imagesData.append(imageData)

                        if counter == images.count {
                            let deliveryAreasArr = Array(deliveryAreas)
                            self.returnedValues = ["name": name, "description": description, "images": imagesData , "category": category, "price": price, "deliveryFee": deliveryFee, "deliveryArea": deliveryAreasArr, "deliveryTime": deliveryTime, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970, "userId": uid]
                            completion(self.returnedValues)
                        }

                    }

                })
            }
        })

    } else {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing Information", message: "All fields are required. Please fill all fields.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        UIActivityIndicatorView.stopActivityIndicator(indicator: self.activityIndicator, container: self.activityIndicatorContainer, loadingView: self.activityIndicatorLoadingView)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a number of conditional unwrap statements there that could fail. If any of them fail then you don't call the completion handler. You should restructure your code so that the handler is always called even if it only has partial results. Call it at the end of the `for` loop using a dispatch group and notify rather than using an unnecessary counter. Your handler should also have an error parameter that indicates something went wrong rather than showing an alert from an asynchronous block. . Returning a dictionary like that is also fairly icky. A struct would be better.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Isn't that what I am doing? if the conditional unwrap fails then I have an alert that handles that. Is that not correct? can you elaborate a bit on dispatch group? I am a newbie here :)

Comment: The alert handles the case where you can't get all of the values from the input dictionary (and it shouldn't be an alert in this function, it should simply call the completion handler with an error), but there are a number of `if` statements inside your `for` that can result in `counter` not being incremented.  If any of these fail then you will never call the completion handler.  I understand you are using the counter in an attempt to know when all of the asynchronous tasks are complete, but a [dispatch group](http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/) is a better solution for this

Comment: Not to mention that several Firebase completion closures promise to return an error? in case of failure but even if they fail they return error=nil and it makes super hard to debug. If putdata fails but you get a nil error then you don’t return just continue without incrementing. So you might never call the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of `if` statements inside your `for` loop that can result in `counter` not being incremented. If any of these fail then you will never call the completion handler.

I understand that you are using the `counter` in an attempt to know when all of the asynchronous tasks are complete, but a dispatch group is a better solution for this.

It is also important that your completion handler is called in all paths; such as when the initial `guard` fails or in the `else` clause of the initial `if` - Your completion handler should probably accept an `Error` parameter so that it knows that there was a problem.

```
//MARK: - Get Form Values

fileprivate func getFormValues(values: [String: Any], completion: @escaping ([String:Any]?)->()) {
    var returnedValues: [String: Any] = [:]

    if let name = values["name"] as? String,
        let description = values["description"] as? String,
        let images = values["images"] as? [UIImage],
        let category = values["category"] as? String,
        let price = values["price"] as? Double,
        let deliveryFee = values["deliveryFee"] as? Double,
        let deliveryAreas = values["deliveryArea"] as? Set<String>,
        let deliveryTime = values["deliveryTime"] as? String {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(nil) 
            return 
        }
        var imagesData = [[String: Any]]()

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // Create a Dispatch Group

        images.forEach({ (image) in

            let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
            let productImageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("product_images").child(uid).child("\(imageName).jpg")
            var resizedImage = UIImage()

            if image.size.width > 800 {
                resizedImage = image.resizeWithWidth(width: 800)!
            }

            if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.5) {

                dispatchGroup.enter()  // Enter the group

                productImageStorageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                   guard error == nil else {
                        print("Failed to upload image: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                        dispatchGroup.leave()  // Leave the dispatch group if there was an error
                        return
                    }

                    //Successfully uploaded product Image
                    print("Successfully uploaded product Image")
                    if let productImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                        let imageData: [String: Any] = [imageName: productImageUrl]
                        imagesData.append(imageData)
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave() // Leave the dispatch group in normal circumstances
                })
            }
        })

        // Schedule a notify closure for execution when the dispatch group is empty

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            let deliveryAreasArr = Array(deliveryAreas)
            returnedValues = ["name": name, "description": description, "images": imagesData , "category": category, "price": price, "deliveryFee": deliveryFee, "deliveryArea": deliveryAreasArr, "deliveryTime": deliveryTime, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970, "userId": uid]
            completion(self.returnedValues)
        }

    } else {
        completion(nil)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing Information", message: "All fields are required. Please fill all fields.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        UIActivityIndicatorView.stopActivityIndicator(indicator: self.activityIndicator, container: self.activityIndicatorContainer, loadingView: self.activityIndicatorLoadingView)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Some other points:

- It would be better to pass structs rather than dictionaries.  Using a `struct` for your input would get rid of that massive `if let` at the start of your function since you would know the types of the values and by making them non-optional properties of the struct you would know that the values were present.
- It is unusual for a function such as this to present an alert; it would normally just return an error via the completion or perhaps `throw` back to the caller to indicate that there was a problem and let the caller handle it
- I don't see why `imagesData` needs to be an array of dictionaries.  Each dictionary in the array only has one entry, so you could just use a dictionary of `[String:String]` (There is no need to use `Any` when you know what the type will be.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This seems to be a step forward. However I am still missing the last item of in the images array. Your solution does work however still skips the last item in the array and does not return it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: this `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.5)` is probably failing for that image - you don't print any error if that fails.

Comment: You are correct. It is failing for one particular image. Not sure why though.